# Zurb Foundation - Inconsistency in Calculating the Size of <h> Elements

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

In Zurb Foundation (5.2.2 and 5.4.5), it seems that there is inconsistency in calculating the size of the h (h1, h2, ..) elements. I changed the value of the relevant scss variable to (23), instead of the default (44) (**$h1-font-size: rem-calc(23);**). This change should make the h1 elements as big as the h4 elements. This takes effect "successfully" for the desktop screen (h1 becomes 1.4375rem). However, the font size becomes so small on a mobile screen (h1 becomes 0.8125rem).

In calculating the font size of the h elements, I think the media queries for the mobile size uses a different base (possibly using the $rem-base variable defined in the scss file) than the base used for desktop (possibly using the browser's default definition for "1 rem" as a base variable.)

To summarize, using (**$h1-font-size: rem-calc(23);** in the scss file), results into the following.

1. on a **desktop**-size scree: **p(1rem), h1(1.4375rem)**
2. on a **mobile**-size screen: **p(1rem), h1(0.8125rem)**

Am I missing something, or there is a bug? If it is a bug, is there a workaround, other than manually updating the css file? My objective is to decrease the size of h1 elements. I want h1 elements to look as big as h4 elements.

Thank you so much for your effort and time...

Answer (score 1):

Foundation has a different variable for font-size on smaller screens.
`$h4-font-reduction`
change the above variable to your needs.
Line -31 of _type.scss

```
$h4-font-reduction: rem-calc(5) !default;
```